# Displaying a listbox inside the ListBox item programmatically - See Answer directly

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, telerik, expandablelistview

I'm a beginner in development for Windows Phone 8. I've installed **Telerik trial kit for Windows Phone in my VS 2012.**

**To do:**
What I wanted to do is to **show a list of items whose each item can get expanded to show another list of items** when a user clicks on the former list's items.

**What I did:**
I've used a RadDataBoundListBox and a RadExpanderControl. The XAML code for which is attached in file - "MainPage.XAML". Since I've used my own ViewModels, I used a sample data file called "SampleData1.XAML", so that I can see its look in the designer tab of my VS 2012. It looks perfect in the designer tab as I toggle between the values (true or false) of IsExpanded property of the RadExpanderControl.

**The problem:**
When I run the application, the outer RadDataBoundListBox (named myListBox) gets its contents neatly and displays correctly. But when I click on any one of its items (i.e. myListBox items), the inner RadDataBoundListBox (named subCategoryListBox) gets its contents correctly but comes behind the myListBox which **causes overlapping of both listbox's items.**

**What it should do:**
On the click of any myListBox item, the subCategoryListBox should open in the space made available after lowering down the other myListBox items.

P.S: The items in both RadDataBoundListBox (i.e myListBox and subCategoryListBox) are loaded programmatically.

MainPage.XAML is:

```
<phone:Panorama Title="oscommerce">
        <phone:Panorama.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/OSCommerce;component/Assets/PanoramaBackground.png"/>
        </phone:Panorama.Background>



        <!--Panorama item one-->


        <phone:PanoramaItem Name="firstPanoramaItem" Header="Categories" Loaded="categories_Loaded">

            <phone:PanoramaItem.Resources>

                <helpers:StringToUpperConverter x:Key="StringToUpperConverter"/>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="telerikPrimitives:RadExpanderControl" x:Key="CustomAnimatedIndicatorExpanderTemplate">
                    <Border
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    x:Name="PART_LayoutRoot"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    Margin="0,0,0,0">

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpandedStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Collapsed" To="Expanded">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                            Duration="0:0:0.250"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedIndicatorRotate"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                            To="180">
                                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            </DoubleAnimation>
                                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                            x:Name="PART_ExpandAnimation"
                                            Duration="0:0:0.250"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ExpandableContentHolder"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                            To="{Binding ElementName=PART_ExpandableContentPresenter, Path=DesiredSize.Height}"> <!--my addition-->

                                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            </DoubleAnimation>
                                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                            Duration="0:0:0.250"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ExpandableContentHolder"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1">
                                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            </DoubleAnimation>
                                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                            Duration="0:0:0.250"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ExpandableContentTranslate"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y"
                                            To="0">
                                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            </DoubleAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Expanded" To="Collapsed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                            Duration="0:0:0.250"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedIndicatorRotate"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                            To="0">
                                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            </DoubleAnimation>
                                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                            Duration="0:0:0.250"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ExpandableContentHolder"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                            To="0">
                                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            </DoubleAnimation>
                                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                            Duration="0:0:0.250"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ExpandableContentHolder"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="0">
                                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            </DoubleAnimation>
                                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                            Duration="0:0:0.250"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ExpandableContentTranslate"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y"
                                            To="-100">
                                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            </DoubleAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation 
                                            Duration="0:0:0.250"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedIndicatorRotate"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                            To="0">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                        <DoubleAnimation 
                                        Duration="0"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ExpandableContentHolder"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                        To="0"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation 
                                        Duration="0"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ExpandableContentHolder"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="0"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation 
                                        Duration="0"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ExpandableContentTranslate"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y"
                                        To="-100"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation 
                                            Duration="0:0:0.250"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedIndicatorRotate"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                            To="180">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                        Duration="0"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ExpandableContentHolder"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                        To="{Binding ElementName=PART_ExpandableContentPresenter, Path=DesiredSize.Height}"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation 
                                        Duration="0"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ExpandableContentHolder"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="1"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation 
                                        Duration="0"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ExpandableContentTranslate"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y"
                                        To="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="300">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="PART_ExpanderHeaderLayoutRoot">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="PART_MainContentPresenter"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                />
                                <ContentPresenter
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding AnimatedIndicatorContent}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding AnimatedIndicatorContentTemplate}"
                                x:Name="PART_AnimatedIndicator"
                                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.47" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                    <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform x:Name="AnimatedIndicatorRotate"/>
                                    </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>

                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </Grid>
                            <Canvas
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            x:Name="PART_ExpandableContentHolder"
                            Height="Auto"
                            Width="396"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter
                                Visibility="Collapsed" 
                                x:Name="PART_ExpandableContentPresenter"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ExpandableContentTemplate}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding ExpandableContent}">

                                    <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="PART_ExpandableContentTranslate"/>
                                    </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </phone:PanoramaItem.Resources>




            <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox Name="myListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="12,3,12,0" SelectionChanged="myListBox_Tap">
                <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <telerikPrimitives:RadExpanderControl ExpandableContent="{Binding}" Content="{Binding}" BorderThickness="0, 3, 0, 0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}" Template="{StaticResource CustomAnimatedIndicatorExpanderTemplate}" Height="Auto">



                            <telerikPrimitives:RadExpanderControl.AnimatedIndicatorContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Margin="0,6,0,15" Source="Images/ExpanderArrow.png" Width="55"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </telerikPrimitives:RadExpanderControl.AnimatedIndicatorContentTemplate>



                            <telerikPrimitives:RadExpanderControl.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Height="100" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Canvas Height="80" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,0,0" Background="PaleGreen">
                                                <Image Height="60" Width="60" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                                            </Canvas>
                                            <StackPanel>
                                                <TextBlock Margin="20,12,0,0" Text="{Binding Title, Converter={StaticResource StringToUpperConverter}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Width="224" Height="34"/>
                                                <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding DateAdded}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Width="224" Height="42"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </telerikPrimitives:RadExpanderControl.ContentTemplate>



                            <telerikPrimitives:RadExpanderControl.ExpandableContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid Margin="40,0,0,0" Height="Auto">

                                                <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox Name="subCategoryListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                                                    <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate>

                                                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="100">
                                                                <Canvas Height="80" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,12,0,0" Background="PaleGreen">
                                                                    <Image Height="60" Width="60" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                                                                </Canvas>
                                                                <StackPanel>
                                                            <TextBlock Margin="20,12,0,0" Text="{Binding Title, Converter={StaticResource StringToUpperConverter}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Width="224" Height="34"/>
                                                                    <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding DateAdded}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Width="224" Height="42"/>
                                                                </StackPanel>
                                                            </StackPanel>

                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox>

                                        </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </telerikPrimitives:RadExpanderControl.ExpandableContentTemplate>
                        </telerikPrimitives:RadExpanderControl>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
    </phone:Panorama>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution now and its pretty simple. Add a ListBox inside the ItemTemplate of another ListBox like this... (You can copy/paste the code below in your XAML.)

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" Margin="0,-28,-22,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="myListBox_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <Border Height="3" Background="White" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,0,0,10" Height="100">
                                <Canvas Width="100" Height="100" Background="#FFFFC702">
                                    <Image Width="80" Height="80" Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="10"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <StackPanel Width="309" Margin="8,0,0,0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateAdded}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,-2,10,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <ListBox Name="innerListBox" Width="367" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="60,0,0,0" Height="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}" Visibility="Collapsed" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="innerListBox_SelectionChanged">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                            <Canvas Width="100" Height="100" Background="#FFFFC702">
                                                <Image Width="80" Height="80" Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="10"/>
                                            </Canvas>
                                            <StackPanel Width="260" Margin="8,-7,0,0">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateAdded}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,-2,10,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Now to access the innerListBox (present inside myListBox), use the following C# code.

```
var _container = myListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myListBox.SelectedItem);
var _children = AllChildren(_container);
ListBox _control = (ListBox)_children.Find(x => x.Name.Equals("innerListBox"));
```

The definition of AllChildren() method is below which you have to also add in C# code:

```
private List<Control> AllChildren(DependencyObject parent)
    {
        List<Control> _List = new List<Control>();
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
        {
            var _child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (_child is Control)
                _List.Add(_child as Control);
            _List.AddRange(AllChildren(_child));
        }
        return _List;
    }
```

Comment: Remove the telerik references at all if you have mistakenly used them (like me) and got stuck and all the using statements also.